# Determining full route of domestic leg

Tags: commercial-aviation

I've come across a JetStar flight (JQ 28 on 3 February 2015) that's flying from Sydney to Melbourne which departs and arrives in international terminals.

My assumption is that it's part of an international flight - that is, it's flying from somewhere overseas to Sydney, and then going on to Melbourne, or that it's flying from Melbourne onwards to somewhere overseas.

I'm interested in whether it's coming from Japan. How can I find out what the full international route is?

Comment: it seems like you're trying to track someone in particular, and that's not what this site is about

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too narrow, and the answers will not help others who are looking for information here. Reword it in a general way, and it will be OK.

Answer (score 1):

[FlightAware.com](http://flightaware.com/) is a good resource for this sort of thing. When you look up a flight, you can click "Track inbound flight" under the flight ID. If [the trip on January 19th/20th](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/JST28/history/20150119/1400Z/VTSP/YSSY) is any indication, it arrived from Phuket, Thailand before continuing to Melbourne.

Comment: In addition to Flightaware, most airline websites have a published schedule so you can easily check the flights each week. However I can't seem to find it on the Jetstar site...